# Egrep special expressions like \w in bracket expressions []

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to use extended grep to extract data from a JSON. The regex I use is functional on my [regexr instance](http://regexr.com/4a682), but for some reason it doesn't work in bash.

I tried many things, notably the [bare double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash) and various minor edits to the regex for escaping.

```
#!/bin/bash
networks='{ "networks": [ { "admin_state_up": true, "availability_zone_hints": [], "availability_zones": [], "created_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z", "description": "", "id": "7188504a-72cb-4590-a9b0-414732017837", "ipv4_address_scope": null, "ipv6_address_scope": null, "is_default": false, "mtu": 1450, "name": "BLUE", "port_security_enabled": true, "project_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e", "provider:network_type": "vxlan", "provider:physical_network": null, "provider:segmentation_id": 86, "revision_number": 2, "router:external": false, "shared": false, "status": "ACTIVE", "subnets": [], "tags": [], "tenant_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e", "updated_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z" }, { "admin_state_up": true, "availability_zone_hints": [], "availability_zones": [], "created_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z", "description": "", "id": "ed82083f-0a7c-4322-a4fb-de8db23e2bae", "ipv4_address_scope": null, "ipv6_address_scope": null, "is_default": false, "mtu": 1450, "name": "RED", "port_security_enabled": true, "project_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e", "provider:network_type": "vxlan", "provider:physical_network": null, "provider:segmentation_id": 108, "revision_number": 2, "router:external": false, "shared": false, "status": "ACTIVE", "subnets": [], "tags": [], "tenant_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e", "updated_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z" }, { "admin_state_up": true, "availability_zone_hints": [], "availability_zones": [], "created_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z", "description": "", "id": "1eb6647e-869e-4e83-9468-43e2c320bccc", "ipv4_address_scope": null, "ipv6_address_scope": null, "is_default": false, "mtu": 1450, "name": "public", "port_security_enabled": true, "project_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e", "provider:network_type": "vxlan", "provider:physical_network": null, "provider:segmentation_id": 32, "revision_number": 2, "router:external": false, "shared": false, "status": "ACTIVE", "subnets": [], "tags": [], "tenant_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e", "updated_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z" } ] }'
result=`echo $networks | grep -oE '"(id|name)": "([\w+-]+)"'`
echo $result
```

The aforementioned code doesn't work but if I switch to the following regex, it works. I just need to add extraction for id field too to be able to extract ids and names using \2 back reference (group 2)

```
grep -oE '"(id|name)": "(\w+)"'
```

Can you help me understand why the script doesn't work?

### Full formatted JSON

```js
{
  "networks": [{
    "admin_state_up": true,
    "availability_zone_hints": [],
    "availability_zones": [],
    "created_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "7188504a-72cb-4590-a9b0-414732017837",
    "ipv4_address_scope": null,
    "ipv6_address_scope": null,
    "is_default": false,
    "mtu": 1450,
    "name": "BLUE",
    "port_security_enabled": true,
    "project_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e",
    "provider:network_type": "vxlan",
    "provider:physical_network": null,
    "provider:segmentation_id": 86,
    "revision_number": 2,
    "router:external": false,
    "shared": false,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "subnets": [],
    "tags": [],
    "tenant_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z"
  }, {
    "admin_state_up": true,
    "availability_zone_hints": [],
    "availability_zones": [],
    "created_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "ed82083f-0a7c-4322-a4fb-de8db23e2bae",
    "ipv4_address_scope": null,
    "ipv6_address_scope": null,
    "is_default": false,
    "mtu": 1450,
    "name": "RED",
    "port_security_enabled": true,
    "project_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e",
    "provider:network_type": "vxlan",
    "provider:physical_network": null,
    "provider:segmentation_id": 108,
    "revision_number": 2,
    "router:external": false,
    "shared": false,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "subnets": [],
    "tags": [],
    "tenant_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z"
  }, {
    "admin_state_up": true,
    "availability_zone_hints": [],
    "availability_zones": [],
    "created_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "1eb6647e-869e-4e83-9468-43e2c320bccc",
    "ipv4_address_scope": null,
    "ipv6_address_scope": null,
    "is_default": false,
    "mtu": 1450,
    "name": "public",
    "port_security_enabled": true,
    "project_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e",
    "provider:network_type": "vxlan",
    "provider:physical_network": null,
    "provider:segmentation_id": 32,
    "revision_number": 2,
    "router:external": false,
    "shared": false,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "subnets": [],
    "tags": [],
    "tenant_id": "187d635aec4c43fe8e8918afb3a5c82e",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-12T23:45:13Z"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Done  I initially thought the root cause was adding the dash to the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> The Backslash Character and Special Expressions
>
> The symbol \w is a synonym for [[:alnum:]] and \W is a synonym for [^[:alnum:]]. `...` A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed by [ and ]. `...` To include a literal ] place it first in the list. Similarly, to include a literal ^ place it anywhere but first. Finally, to include a literal - place it last.

Basically, `\w` is *literally* replaced by those characters when evaluated, giving you `"([[[:alnum:]]+-]+)"`, which in a US standard locale gives you `"([[a-zA-Z0-9]+-]+)"`.

Since a bracket expression is truncated by the first `]` it sees (unless it is the first element of a bracket expression), the group is only `[[[:alnum:]]+`, or "1 or more of a digit, letter, and `[`. This expression is followed by `-]+`, meaning "exactly one hyphen and one or more `]`". This is obviously pretty terrible.

If you try

```
echo $networks | grep -oE '"(id|name)": "([[:alnum:]+-]+)"'
```

I.e., `\w` without the outer bracket expression, the relevant part means "a group (surrounded by `"`) comprised of one or more digits, letters, hyphens, and plus signs", which outputs:

```
"id": "7188504a-72cb-4590-a9b0-414732017837"
"name": "BLUE"
"id": "ed82083f-0a7c-4322-a4fb-de8db23e2bae"
"name": "RED"
"id": "1eb6647e-869e-4e83-9468-43e2c320bccc"
"name": "public"
```

Comment: +1 I was adding same answer, from [How to match sets of character using grep](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/). Using `[[:alnum:]]` looks like a great workaround to using backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Using PERL (`-P`) instead of Extended (`-E`) regexp, looks like the `\w` is interpreted as expected, without escaping issue: note the `-oP`

```
result=$( echo $networks | grep -oP '"(id|name)": "([\w+-]+)"' ) ; 
echo $result
"id": "7188504a-72cb-4590-a9b0-414732017837" "name": "BLUE" "id": "ed82083f-0a7c-4322-a4fb-de8db23e2bae" "name": "RED" "id": "1eb6647e-869e-4e83-9468-43e2c320bccc" "name": "public"
```

Comment: This worked for me in my target environment, however, `-P` didn't work when I tested on macOS because version of grep is `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`, whereas my target environment has `grep (GNU grep) 3.1`. Good to know, thanks again for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (it does not resolve the "escaping `\w` issue)

```
result=$( echo $networks | grep -oE '"(id|name)": "([a-zA-Z_+-]+)"' ) ; 
echo $result
```

Prints me:

```
"name": "BLUE" "name": "RED" "name": "public"
```

Note: prefer using `$( )` syntax to execute sub shells rather than the backtick.